# How to write Select * from table t where t.col1=t.col2 in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to write following SQL query in mongodb ?

`Select * from table t where t.col1=t.col2`

Comment: Use `db.col.find({$expr:{$eq:["$col1", "$col2"]}})`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) aggregation operator which:

> Restricts the contents of the documents based on information stored in the documents themselves.

For instance:

```
db.col.save({a: 1, b: 1});
db.col.save({a: 2, b: 1});

db.col.aggregate([
    { $redact: {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ "$a", "$b" ] },
           then: "$$KEEP",
           else: "$$PRUNE"
         }
       }
     }
])
```